# Почему скачиваются поврежденные файлы?

Tags: java, android

Используя этот код файлы постоянно скачиваются поврежденными. При том что тестировались разные файлы для скачивания в формате apk, в разных приложениях, для часов и для телефона, и с разных хостингов. Может данная ситуация происходит из за того что меняется название файла в коде или же по причине что я не указываю все пермишены именно в коде а пытаюсь скачать без разрешения пользователя на устройстве?

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url + ""));
            request.setTitle(fileName);
            request.setMimeType("*/*");
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: а как у вас организован слушатель загрузки?

Comment: SetonclickListener на кнопке

Comment: Ну так добавьте в вопрос

Comment: А что значит "повреждёнными"? Файл пустой, недокачан, содержит другие данные (например html страницу, сообщающую об ошибке доступа к файлу)?

Comment: Недокачан, скачивает всего 238кб из нескольких мб

Comment: Но это точно начало нужного файла, а не что-то другое? `DownloadManager` не покажет уведомление об успешном завершении загрузки, если она не завершена корректно.